# wordpress child theme css style gets over ridden

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, parent-child

I am using Wordpress with the swift ideas neighborhood theme, which is running on the swift and the twitter bootstrap framework.

To change some styles of the Theme I'm also using a child theme, which for now just has a style.css and is working fine for some parts. However, I now wanted to change some of the bootstrap responsive styles for different screen sizes and that doesn't work.

My Problem is, that the responsive.css of the mother theme always over rides the styles of the child theme for different screen sizes.

Here I'll show you what I wanted to change. First, I load two different .css files of my mother theme like this

```
@import url("../neighborhood/style.css");
@import url("../neighborhood/css/responsive.css");
```

And following, this is the style of the mother theme that I want to change:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
(...)
body.woocommerce .has-no-sidebar ul.products li.product, body.woocommerce .has-no-sidebar .upsells.products ul.products li.product {
      width: 270px;
}
(...)
}
```

In my child theme style.css I changed this line like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    body.woocommerce .has-no-sidebar ul.products li.product, body.woocommerce .has-no-sidebar .upsells.products ul.products li.product {
        width: 31%;
    }
}
```

For me, this looks all good but the style of the responsive.css of my mother theme always over rides the code of my child theme. Where did I make a mistake?

Thanks in advance, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: try with an !important extension, and if that doesn't work, maybe wordpress is overwriting your files somewhere, are you inserting your stylesheets into header module?

Comment: Thanks a lot, the !important extension helps. Sometimes it can be so easy:)

Comment: i posted an answer too, if u could just... :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with an !important extension, and if that doesn't work, maybe wordpress is overwriting your files somewhere, are you inserting your stylesheets into header module? –

Answer (score 0):

I came across the exact same problem. The responsive.css overrides the child theme css. In my case using !important seems to fail because responsive.css is already using !important:

```
// Code from responsive.css
#main-navigation {
  display: none;
  float: none;
  margin: 10px 20px 30px!important;
}
```